# Connect a local git repo to google cloud VM

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to link a local python flask repo to my remote (production) vm in the google cloud.

On Google VM :

```
sudo mkdir /home/git && cd /home/git
sudo mkdir flask_project.git && cd flask_project.git
sudo git init --bare

sudo vim hooks/post-receive
{Added}
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/flask_project git checkout -f

sudo chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

On Local dev

```
git init
git remote add production web@<externalip>:/home/git/flask_project.git
```

I've generated SSH keys and added public key to GCP Metadata but when I push commits from local to remote :

```
git push production master
```

Git stalls and the commit doesn't reach remote.

Any ideas how I can link the repo's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/home/git/flask_project.git` bare repo is owned by `root` after the steps you executed.

But you're attempting to operate it as `web` (according to your remote production config), which doesn't have write permissions on the bare repo. I suspect that depending on the OS this may cause the hanging - on my older opensuse it just fails with:

> remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objects

Try `sudo chown -R web /home/git/flask_project.git`

Alternatively, if you plan to push to that repo as multiple users (`git` comes to mind), you could use the `git init --bare --shared`  to create the bare repo instead. Not a great practice, tho.

Side note: you also need to clone the repo in `/home/www/flask_project` (as `web` as well) before the hook can operate properly, otherwise you'll probably get something like:

> remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree