# Run a command on remote after local git is pushed to remote

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform

I have a git post-receive hook set up on my remote VM :

```
  GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/flask_project git checkout -f
```

When I commit my local changes and push to remote the files get copied to the worktree.  This is working well.

I need to re-start flask with the command :

```
sudo supervisorctl restart flask_project
```

To save me logging on the remote VPN can I run this command after the remote repo is pushed to so the content is refreshed in the flask app?

Comment: Why not add it to the hook, just like the rest of the commands you had in the somehow related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436125/connect-a-local-git-repo-to-google-cloud-vm?

Comment: Supervisor needs su !!! Grr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git` is geared towards versioning content, and also has enough hooks and functionalities to look like a deployment tool, but you will often run into some form of limitation when using directly the `git` command as your main deployment tool.

I would advise you to start listing the deployment actions in some separate script.

---

To answer your question :

Edit your `sudoers` config to allow the deployment user to execute `sudo supervisorctl restart flask_project` with no password.

Comment: I'm experimenting to see if it's possible to use a lightweight method for deployment with python.  I'll separate out the minor commands into a script.   SU is already configured for no password with the google cloud.